# new data set with combining some rows

Tags: r, dataframe

This is not a question about long and wide shape:!!!!! don't make it duplicate plz

Suppose I have :

```
 HouseholdID.  PersonID.   time.     dur.    age
      1            1         3        4       19
      1            2         3        4       29
      1            3         5        5       30
      1            1         5        5       18
      2            1         21       30      18
      2            2         21       30      30
```

In each household some people have the same time and dur.  want to combine only rows whose have the same HouseholdID,time and dur

OUTPUT:

```
   HouseholdID.  PersonID.   time.   dur.   age.  HouseholdID.  PersonID.  time.    dur.    age
       1            1         3        4      19     1            2         3        4       29
       1            3         5        5      30     1            1         5        5       18
       2            1         21       30     18     2            2         21       30      30
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the purpose of such a data structure?

Comment: I am gonna put them in the matrix AX<b in the model

Comment: I can rearrange columns as I want

Comment: @shere Can you please format the expected output

Comment: @akrun I did, Notice I just want to put rows next to each other with the same value for time and dur. I have more 10 columns in my data but it doesn't matter if those values are the same or not

Comment: in the first family the first and second person are in the same row because they have the same time and dur, also person 3 and 1 (third and forth row). in the second family person 1 and 2 have the same value in those 2 columns so they are in the same row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), HouseholdID. ~ rowid(HouseholdID.), 
      value.var = c("PersonID.", "time.", "dur.", "age"), sep="")
#   HouseholdID. PersonID.1 PersonID.2 time.1 time.2 dur.1 dur.2 age1 age2
#1:            1          1          2      3      3     4     4   19   29
#2:            2          1          2     21     21    30    30   18   30
```

---

Or an option with `pivot_wider` from the devel version of `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr) # ‘0.8.3.9000’
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(HouseholdID.) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols= HouseholdID., names_from = rn, 
              values_from = c(PersonID., time., dur., age), name_sep="")
# A tibble: 2 x 9
#  HouseholdID. PersonID.1 PersonID.2 time.1 time.2 dur.1 dur.2  age1  age2
#         <int>      <int>      <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1            1          1          2      3      3     4     4    19    29
#2            2          1          2     21     21    30    30    18    30
```

#### Update

With the new dataset, extend the id columns by including the 'time.' and 'dur.'

```
dcast(setDT(df2), HouseholdID. + time. + dur. ~ rowid(HouseholdID., time., dur.), 
          value.var = c("PersonID.", "age"), sep="")
```

If we need duplicate columns for 'time.' and 'dur.' (not clear why it is needed though)

```
dcast(setDT(df2), HouseholdID. + time. + dur. ~ rowid(HouseholdID., time., dur.), 
       value.var = c("PersonID.", "time.", "dur.", "age"), sep="")[, 
            c('time.', 'dur.') := NULL][]
#   HouseholdID. PersonID.1 PersonID.2 time..11 time..12 dur..11 dur..12 age1 age2
#1:            1          1          2        3        3       4       4   19   29
#2:            1          3          1        5        5       5       5   30   18
#3:            2          1          2       21       21      30      30   18   30
```

Or with `tidyverse`

```
df2 %>% 
    group_by(HouseholdID., time., dur.) %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_wider(id_cols= c(HouseholdID., time., dur.), names_from = rn, 
               values_from = c(PersonID., age), names_sep = "")
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  HouseholdID. time.  dur. PersonID.1 PersonID.2  age1  age2
#         <int> <int> <int>      <int>      <int> <int> <int>
#1            1     3     4          1          2    19    29
#2            1     5     5          3          1    30    18
#3            2    21    30          1          2    18    30
```

NOTE: `duplicate` column names are not recommended as it can lead to confusion in identification of columns.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(HouseholdID. = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), PersonID. = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), time. = c(3L, 3L, 21L, 21L), dur. = c(4L, 4L, 30L, 
30L), age = c(19L, 29L, 18L, 30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))


df2 <- structure(list(HouseholdID. = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), PersonID. = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), time. = c(3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 21L, 21L), dur. = c(4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 30L, 30L), age = c(19L, 29L, 30L, 18L, 18L, 30L)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Please see edit, we have more than one pair in each household

Comment: I don't know why still some rows come next to each other with different time values

Comment: @shere  Based on your example, it is giving the expected

Comment: the first one doesn't give a correct output, the second :could not find function "pivot_wider" I loaded that library but still error

Comment: @shere I checked your expected output and it is showing the same output (columns reorder) with `dcast`